# Joining hex values to create a 16bit value

Tags: objective-c, bit-manipulation

Im receiving three uint8 values which are the Most, Middle and Least Significant Digits of a plot value:

EG: Printed in console (%c):

```
   1 A 4
```

I need to pass them into a signal view UI grapher which accepts a uint16_t. So far the way im doing it is not working correctly.

```
 uint16_t iChanI = (bgp->iChanIH << 8) + (bgp->iChanIM <<4 ) + bgp->iChanIL;
 uint16_t iChanQ = (bgp->iChanQH << 8) + (bgp->iChanQM <<4) + bgp->iChanQL;

[self updateSView:iChanI ichanQ:iChanQ];
```

Am i merging them correctly, or just adding the values?

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks,

Comment: Looks right to me. Something else must be wrong. Post sample values of input and output of this fragment.

Comment: *"Am i merging them correctly, or just adding the values?"* - why don't you log the values or inspect them in the debugger to check? (If the are printed as '1', 'A', '4' then the values are 0x31, 0x41, 0x34 and the result is probably not what you want.)

Comment: Okay so i'm receiving hex values and i need to convert them into byte values.

Comment: "hex" is a representation of a number. 'byte' is a certain amount of information. You can't convert hex into bytes, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to convert each hex character to its equivalent 4 bit (nybble) representation, and then merge them into an `int16_t`, e.g.

```
uint8_t to_nybble(char c)
{
    return 'c' >= '0' && c <= '9' ? c - '0' : c - 'A' + 10;
}

uint16_t iChanI = (to_nybble(bgp->iChanIH) << 8) |
                  (to_nybble(bgp->iChanIM) << 4) |
                   to_nybble(bgp->iChanIL);
```