# Merging MSD and LSD

Tags: objective-c, bit-manipulation

I have two 4 bit hex values A, B and I want to create an 8 bit value with A the MSD and B the LSD:

This is my attempt:

```
  uint8_t X = (A << 4) & (B);
```

I am getting a value but unsure if it is correct.

Is this a correct method of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be:

```
uint8_t X = (A << 4) | (B); 
                    ^^^
```

This is because you need to [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) (`|`) the two values together to combine them, not [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) (`&`).

See [this answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17048122/253056) for a similar example where nybble values are combined using bitwise OR.